# SSH session closses on TAB key

Tags: raspbmc, ssh, linux

Since I upgrade the RaspMBC distribution in my Pi I have been experiencing a strange problem with SSH. When I connect to Pi using putty and press TAB, putty closes. I tried different versions of putty and a console ssh client but the problem seems to be somewhere in the Pi.

Any ideas? Using SSH without autocomplete is not very comfortable.

Comment: Ouch ... That must be painful. But its a strange error. Do you have another Pi / Card to try. POssibly something iffy happened during the upgrade. DOuble check your keyboard layout or localization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reinstall RaspBMC because I could not find any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

you may try to login from the console (connect your TV to HDMI output and use real USB keyboard), in this case you'll at least see the error messages, if something is wrong with your config files.

Comment: there is no error message, I get logged out